# changing ssh port caused refuse to connect

Tags: linux, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

these are the steps I followed to change the default ssh port

1. login to compute engine instance using gcutil ssh
2. cd /etc/ssh
3. sudo nano sshd_config --> changed the port to some number lets say for the example: 1111
4. saved and exit
5. sudo service ssh restart ---> [ ok ] Restarting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
6. open a new terminal and repeated step 1 ---> ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused ----> the change succeded
7. went to my GCE console and added a firewall with the tcp:1111
8. tried to connect again with gcutil ssh ---> ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
   I'm not following why after enabling the port 1111 on the GCE gcutil ssh still tries to connect on port 22

   INFO: Running command line: ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /Users/MyUser/.ssh/google_compute_engine -A -p 22 MyUser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --

what am i missing? should I download my ssh key again after changing the port? and if so how do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/reference/other#ssh) clearly states how to provide an alternate ssh port for `gcutil ssh`.

```
  --ssh_port: TCP port to connect to
    (default: '22')
    (an integer)
```

in your case:

```
gcutil ssh --ssh_port=1111 <instance name>
```

Comment: why waist time writing an answer if you don't supply any useful data??? as mentioned above i DID change the ssh port but when trying to reconnect it fails so obviously the problem lies in the client side, but I don't know where to configure the ssh command to run with different port i can always connect with the full command: `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /Users/Kukula/.ssh/google_compute_engine -A -p 1111 Kukula@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` but that is not what i'm asking so if you do know the answer and willing to share i'd appreciate it

Comment: Your question never mentioned that you did this - and it still doesn't. If you actually did, then you need to edit your question.

Comment: I suggest you first read what i wrote step 6 states : The change succeeded, before being condescending!

Comment: @KukulaMula No one is being condescending here. We are trying to help you. AGAIN, you need to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem, still don't know which file to change inorder for the standart `gcutil ssh <machine_name>` to call the new port in your case 1111, @Michael Hampton answer was correct, but he didn't wrapped it within the entire command which confused you so try the following command i believe it will work and you'll be able to connect with your instance

`gcutil ssh --ssh_port 1111 <machine_name>`

Answer (score 0):

> ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /Users/MyUser/.ssh/google_compute_engine -A -p 22 MyUser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

That "-p 22" tells the ssh command to try to connect to a server on port 22.
Change the 22 to the port you have your server running on and you should be good to go.